# Angular's observable is never successful

Tags: javascript, angular

I am new to full stack development. I started with small MEAN application and I am facing following issue:

```
//register user
    this.authservice.registerUser(newUser).subscribe(data =>{
      if(data.success){
         this.flashmessage.show('You are now register and can log in', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000});
         this.router.navigate(['/login']);
      }
      else{
        this.flashmessage.show('Something went wwrong', {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});
        this.router.navigate(['/register']);
      }
    });
```

I am calling this function on the register button's `(click)`, the data is successfully going into the database and I see it works if I execute the backend API manually outside of Angular. But in Angular, this function is going into the `else` and showing the error message even after a successful insert.

Please can someone tell me where is the issue exactly?

Answer (score 0):

The right way to subscribe to an observable and execute some code if something fails is:

```
this.authservice.registerUser(newUser).subscribe(data => {
     this.flashmessage.show('You are now register and can log in', {cssClass: 'alert-success', timeout: 3000});
     this.router.navigate(['/login']);
  },
  error => {
    this.flashmessage.show('Something went wrong: ' + error, {cssClass: 'alert-danger', timeout: 3000});
    this.router.navigate(['/register']);
  });
```

The reason is that the first parameter to the `subscribe` function only gets executed when your request is satisfactory (so no point in validating inside of it if it was successful or not, we know it's successful). To execute something if the request is not successful you use a second function, passed as the second parameter to `subscribe`.

Also, if next time you want to debug a problem, inspect your variables with: `console.log("my_var:", my_var)`, which will print in your browser's console all the contents of the variable `my_var`. If you are using Chrome, open the Dev Tools (press F12) to show the console.